# Magento 2 : Creating popup

Tags: magento2, database, customer, popup

I want to show a popup window as soon as user logged into store. 
I want to show that popup only for some customer (like premium).

Comment: you need popup code for all?

Comment: code for how to create popup and if anyone got logic then just logic.

Comment: hey you try this?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel Directly we need to add it in app\code\vendor\module\view\frontend\templates with custom content?

Comment: Yes You can please try it. if not works then let me know. but after save please clear cache.

Comment: And yes first check the default theme then you can add with your extension ok.

Comment: Its not working after cuustomer logging in. @sarveshDineshkumarPatel

Comment: I just added for when you click on More info that time it will popup You need to do coding for after login. for that, you need to do autoload. as per you said I just give popup code. thanks

Comment: you need to call $(".bt-action-file").modal(options).modal('openModal'); after customer login you need to call this. ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102247/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-akash-killedar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do like this
you need to put this code as your redirect page or any common phtml file.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
?>
<div class="bt-action-file" style="display: none;">Content here</div>

<script>
require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {

            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: false,
                title: 'My Title',
                buttons: []
            };

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $(".bt-action-file").modal(options).modal('openModal');

            });

        }
    );
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope it works!