# How to rewrite jquery code in jquery ui widget

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, widget, widgets

How to remake this code in ui jquery widget?

There is such jquery code. When you select an item using the checkbox, the item is cloned and added to another block.
Tell me how to rewrite it in jquery ui widget since magento uses them to inject js code. Even if you have suggestions on how to improve the code, then I would love to read your ideas :)

I will also be glad of any help from such examples, thanks

example on codepen: https://codepen.io/annbin/pen/VwYRerL

Comment: yes so you need to ad only that js code or add its library js files too?

Comment: please check here I added jquery code. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298841/magento-2-creating-popup/298844 so you get idea okay.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel I don't quite understand you. I only need to convert the logic of this code to more similar to jquery widgets

Comment: Yes that is why I given complete code. now you need to code it. please try it. or if you can not do I can do for you.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel I tried, I just do not have enough knowledge. As it turned out, I find elements incorrectly through the code, I need something different, for example, through events. I don’t quite understand how the jquery widgets methods that start with underscore work. That's why I asked for help

Comment: ok i will do help

Comment: you know basic jquery or not?

Comment: if you not then you need to know that

Comment: if you know jquery then I will go ahead with basic example.

Comment: you have my id please send it.