# magento2 javascript popup ajax

Tags: magento2.3

i user ajax to create popup. I have file app/code/Commercers/Course/view/frontend/templates/managecourse.phtml

```
<td>
   <a href="#ajax-information" name="information-part" id="information-part" type="submit">View Information</a>
</td>

<div id="ajax-information" class="white-popup no-display" >
<table id="my-person-table" class="data-table">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
        <col width="1">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="first last">
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Date From</th>
            <th>Date To</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="course_name"></td>
                <td id="course_detail"></td>
                <td id="course_datefrom"></td>
                <td id="course_dateto"></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/translate'
], function($, modal, $t){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            buttons: []
        };
        var popup = modal(options, $('#ajax-information'));
        $("#information-part").on('click',function(){
            var courseId = $('#courseId').attr('value');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "Information",
                data: {
                    courseId : courseId
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $("#course_name").html(response.name);
                    $("#course_detail").html(response.details_information);
                    $("#course_datefrom").html(response.date_from);
                    $("#course_dateto").html(response.date_to);
                }
            });
            $("#ajax-information").modal("openModal");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And my file controller

```
<?php
namespace Commercers\Course\Controller\Manage;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Information extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    echo 1;exit;
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}

}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Hi, so you want the popup. right?

Comment: Please try to like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298841/magento-2-creating-popup/298844#298844

Comment: Yes thank you guys. i completed

Comment: So you get idea from my answer?

Comment: @Hunng Nguyen  great cool

Comment: I created and sended data. And i deleted loadlayour and renderlayout

Comment: ok cool mate....

Comment: excuse me, can I ask you to help me with a small problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109157/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-hng-nguyn).